# Reentry in Semaphore

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Is there some similar implementation of `Semaphore` or `SemaphoreSlim` that allows reentry? 
What is the best way to implement this feature, it is safe use  `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` and `ConcurrentDictionary` or maybe a field with `[ThreadStatic]` attribute?

Comment: Why do you need this?  It seems like a bad idea.  Why can you not simply release the semaphore before deciding if you need to re-enter it later?  Alternatively, why can you not wrap the semaphore entry around the branching code rather than placing it in the middle?

Comment: Composing a single locked resource from multiple methods that are composed in different ways, for code-reuse.

Comment: You could use an AsyncLocal variable for reentry, and it would work even from different threads. It flows with the execution context, so you could check it to see if you've already acquire a SemphoreSlim in the current (recursive) flow, and skip taking out the SemaphorSlim if you already have it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what library SemaphoreSlim is from, but in general, a "recursive" semaphore would not make sense in the same way that a recursive mutex makes sense.  A semaphore can be *used* as a mutex, but it can also be used for other purposes.  Adding the 'recursive' feature to a mutex makes it more powerful.  Adding the 'recursive' feature to a semaphore would detract from its power.